# How to get result from createAsyncThunk in React component Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I was migrating from Apollo client to Redux toolkit and I am confusing how to use the result(success or error) of API call with `createAsyncThunk` and call `history.push('/')` and `setSubmitting(false)` in my React component.

Example how I did with `Formik` and `Apollo Client`:

```
      onSubmit={async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    signInMutation({
      variables: {
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password,
      },
    }).then(
      (response) => {
        if (response.data.signIn.accessToken) {
          localStorage.setItem(
            AUTH_TOKEN,
            response.data.signIn.accessToken,
          );
          if (response.data.signIn.User.isNew) {
            history.push('/welcome-page');
          } else {
            history.push('/');
          }
          setSubmitting(false);
        }
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(`error signin ${err}`);
        enqueueSnackbar(err.message, {
          variant: 'error',
        });
        setSubmitting(false);
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call `createAsyncThunk`, it will return an `Action Creator` which `redux-thunk` can use.

You should use the function like this:

```js
const actionCreator = createAsyncThunk('prefix', async function echo(text) {
  return text;
});

// app.js
import { unwrapResult } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        dispatch(actionCreator('233'))
          .then(unwrapResult)
          .then((result) => {
            console.log(result); // => 233
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error); // if there is an error
          });
      }}
    >
      Echo
    </button>
  );
}
```

This is what `unwrapResult` does:

```
// @reduxjs/toolkit
export function unwrapResult<R extends ActionTypesWithOptionalErrorAction>(
  returned: R
): PayloadForActionTypesExcludingErrorActions<R> {
  if ('error' in returned) {
    throw returned.error
  }
  return (returned as any).payload
}
```

To handle errors, there are two ways. The first is to throw them directly, and the second is to return `rejectWithValue`.

```js
async function echo(text, { rejectWithValue }) {
  if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
    // throw new Error('error msg');
    // return rejectWithValue('error value');
  }
  return text;
}

dispatch(actionCreator('233'))
  .then(unwrapResult)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result); // => 233
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // by throw new Error('error msg');
    console.log(error.message); // => error msg
    // by return rejectWithValue('error value')
    console.log(error); // => error value
  });
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. How can I return reject promise from `dispatch(actionCreator('233'))`. Because I can handle when successful but cannot handle error cases.